# glowing text dark background

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to make glowing text with css on a dark background.  Here's what I've got:

```css
    .blackbox, .whitebox {
     padding: 20px;
     display: table;
     border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .whitebox { 
     background-color: white; 
     color: black; 
     text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    }
    .blackbox { 
     background-color: black; 
     color: white; 
     text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="whitebox">
    Hi there.
    </div>
    
    <div class="blackbox">
    Hi there.
    </div>
```

The black text in the white box is showing the glow that I defined as black, but the white text in the black box shows nothing.  What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: The white shadow is showing up, it just isn't as easy to see as the black

Comment: the white text is showing a glow, but its harder to see.

Comment: Looks fine to me on Chrome and FF

Comment: As already indicated above, the shadow is showing up and so voted to close.

Comment: I think the obvious followup question for me is, How can I make a glow show up better.  I doubt it can be done, so I'll find other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

[Text shadow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp) property parameters are as follows

```
text-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur-radius color|none|initial|inherit;
```

h-shadow and v-shadow are horizontal and vertical distances. You need to adjust that as well to get the proper shadow. Look at the snippet below.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .blackbox,
        .whitebox {
            padding: 20px;
            display: table;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        
        .whitebox {
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
        }
        
        .blackbox {
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            text-shadow: 8px 8px 5px #fff
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="whitebox">
        Hi there.
    </div>

    <div class="blackbox">
        Hi there.
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The white and black shadows are showing in same intensity. But our eyes are more sensitive to the black shadow rather than white shadow. Try changing the `h-shadow` and `v-shadow` properties

Answer (score 0):

Add something to encapsulate the text inside

```css
.blackbox,
.whitebox {
  padding: 20px;
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.whitebox {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}
.blackbox {
  background-color: black;
}
.blackbox p {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="whitebox">
  Hi there.
</div>

<div class="blackbox">
  <p>Hi there.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't really see a difference.  I still can't see a glow.  Perhaps it's there, but it's too subtle to detect.  I think I'm going to have to resolve this issue with images.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding multiple text shadows as shown in the snippet below. 
To bring a cool effect use different neon colors in the subsequent shadow colors.

```css
    .blackbox, .whitebox {
     padding: 20px;
     display: table;
     border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .whitebox { 
     background-color: white; 
     color: black;
     text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
    }
    .blackbox { 
     background-color: black; 
     color: white; 
     text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff;
    }
```

```html
<div class="whitebox">
  Hi there.
</div>

<div class="blackbox">
  <p>Hi there.</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers.